# Is there a way to convert a PDF into a password protected and encrypted one using iOS's Core Graphics?

Tags: objective-c, ios, pdf, core-graphics

The title says it: I would like to open a PDF on an iOS5 device, set a password on it and save it back using AES256 encryption as described in Adobe's PDF specifications.
I know that opening and reading PDFs is easy with Core Graphics, but what about saving them/converting them and setting the limitations (no open, no printing, no copying, ...)?

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Yes, you can create encrypted PDF files using CoreGraphics. The CGPDFContextCreate method lets you specify in auxiliaryInfo parameter the passwords, access rights and key size. Only AllowCopy and AllowPrint access rights are supported. The document will be encrypted using RC4 algorithm, AES128 and AES256 are not supported.

Comment: Nope. The generated PDF file is PDF 1.5 and AES128 was introduced in PDF 1.6, AES256 was introduced in PDF 1.7 Extension Level 3 (Acrobat 9).

Answer (score 1):

I believe you can.

`CGPDFContextCreate` takes a dictionary in which you can send a password as one of the attributes. The details for `CGPDFContxtCreate` you'll find in [Apple's reference docs](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Auxiliary_Dictionary_Keys).

And the password setting information you'll find again [Apple's docs here](http://developer.apple.com/library/ios/documentation/GraphicsImaging/Reference/CGPDFContext/Reference/reference.html#//apple_ref/doc/constant_group/Auxiliary_Dictionary_Keys).

Comment: But I will have to read and paint each page in the context of the new PDF I suppose? I cannot see a way to say "take this PDF from that URL and save it with these options".